# Is there any way to force Portrait UIInterfaceOrientation for full screen video

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, uiinterfaceorientation

I was searching it but could not found a solution. I want to support only `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` for the application. However, there is a VC for playing video. I am using these for *other VCs*

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}


- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

I know that's the way but. Is there any way to support only `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` but can play video in fullscreen Landscape mode? For example rotating the layer by 90 degree

Comment: display the screen in portrait and just rotate the video...

Comment: @Sulthan Will it be expand?